# Is there a way to receive notification when app is killed? That is when app is not working in foreground or background in iOS

Tags: ios

I am using APNS push with content-type = 1. I receive the payload and fire using local notification.

this works fine in background and foreground mode
but when app is killed I get nothing.
what is the solution? I have seen people saying something about VOIP apps
but mine is not a VOIP app..

Some said to check Pushkin framework?
Any guidance?

### Update

with this Json format I received notification when app was in killed state.. I checked on lower version 9.3 iOS.. have to check on iOS 11..

```
{
    "aps": {
        "content-available": 1,
        "alert": "custom message ",
        "badge": 1,
        "sound": "solemn.wav"
    },
    "id": "55",
    "data": "your data"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can be done if your app is not a VOIP app. But, if you want to change the appearance of a push notification, you may want to look at the [Notification Service Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension).

You have to include mutable-content flag as 1 in your payload inside aps. You cannot use content-type flag with this notification. Also, you have to show user something or the other after you have received the payload. Also, it is available in iOS 10 and above only.

Even with all these constraints, you can do some amazing things with this extension which were not possible earlier.
You can now show media attachment in the notification. 
You can download small content or hit an API. 
You can modify earlier sent push notification.
You can create a local notifcation center in your app.

Comment: I basically wanted my push to show when app is running in foreground, background and if app is killed. So when app is killed there is no way to show push as per what you said and what I saw in general right? My supports upto 4s phones so can't use UNNotification I believe.

Comment: @starterMac: You can not use silent push notification when app is in killed state, but you can ofcourse use normal remote push notification. You can also shedule local notifications but yes you can not hit a service and schedule a local push notifictaion according to it.

Comment: but if I don't use silent notification I will not receive payload in background right? can we get both normal and silent push notification at same time?

Comment: @starterMac: The only way to achieve it that I know of, is to use Notification Service.

Comment: with this Json format I received notification when app was in killed state.. I checked on lower version 9.3 iOS.. have to check on iOS 11..                                                             {
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1 ,
        "alert" : "custom message  ",
        "badge" : 1,
        "sound" : "solemn.wav"
    },
        "id" : "55",
        "data" : "your data"
}